# Ajax does not work in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to make registration in CodeIgniter. Everything is fine, however, I want to add Ajax to show error and success messages. However, it does not work. Here is my view:

```
<div class="modal-body">

                  <div id="messages"></div>
                  <?php $attributes = array('class' => 'rex-forms', 'name' => 'registrationform', 'id' => 'registrationform'); ?>
                  <?= form_open_multipart('user/register', $attributes); ?>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></span>
                        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя пользователя">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('mail'); ?></span>
                        <input name="mail" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Электронный адрес">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password2'); ?></span>
                        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Пароль">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Повторный ввод пароля">
                      </div>                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" name="submitforreg" class="rex-bottom-medium rex-btn-icon">
                        <span class="rex-btn-text">регистрация</span>
                        <span class="rex-btn-text-icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></span>
                    </button>  
                  </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url', 'security'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('User_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->register();
    }



    function register()
    {
        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_dash|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|is_unique[instructors.instructors_slug]xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mail', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[instructors.mail]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|md5|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|md5|matches[password]');


        $to_email= $this->input->post('mail');

        $data['courses'] = $this->popular_courses_model->get_popular_courses();
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();


        //validate form input
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // fails
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            //insert the user registration details into database
            $data = array(
                'instructors_slug' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'mail' => $to_email,
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );

            // insert form data into database
            if ($this->user_model->insertUser($data)) {



                if ($this->user_model->sendEmail($to_email)) {
                    // successfully sent mail
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully Registered! Please confirm the mail sent to your Email-ID!!!</div>');
                    redirect('user/register');
                }
                else
                {
                    // error
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">'.$to_email.'  gondermir '.$this->email->print_debugger().'</div>');
                    redirect('user/register');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">daxil elemir</div>');
                    redirect('user/register');
            }
        }
    }

    public function login(){
            $data['title'] = 'Sign In';
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_dash|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|md5|min_length[3]');

            if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
                $this->load->view('login/login', $data);
            } else {

                // Get username
                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                // Get and encrypt the password
                $password = $this->input->post('password');
                // Login user
                $user_id = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);
                if($user_id){
                    // Create session

                    $user_data = array(
                        'instructor_id' => $instructor_id,
                        'id' => $id,
                        'instructors_slug' => $username,
                        'name' => $name,
                        'logged_in' => true
                        );

                    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

                    redirect('');
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Неверныый логин или пароль');
                    redirect('');
                }       
            }
        }

        public function logout() {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('instructor_id');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('id');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('instructors_slug');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('name');

            redirect('');
        }


    function verify($hash=NULL)
    {
        if ($this->user_model->verifyEmailID($hash))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('verify_msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your Email Address is successfully verified! Please login to access your account!</div>');
            redirect('');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('verify_msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Sorry! There is error verifying your Email Address!</div>');
            redirect('');
        }
    }



}
?>
```

and here is my register.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#registrationform").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) {                
                if(response.success == true) {
                    $("#messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                      response.messages+
                    '</div>');

                    $("#registerForm")[0].reset();
                    $(".text-danger").remove();
                    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

                }
                else {
                    $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
                        var element = $("#"+index);

                        $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .removeClass('has-error')
                        .removeClass('has-success')
                        .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                        .find('.text-danger').remove();

                        $(element).after(value);

                    });
                }
            } // /success
        });  // /ajax

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: what's going wrong what error it throws in console?

Comment: @Curiousdev it just does not work and gives an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at register.js:1

Comment: that means you missed to adding a jquery `min js` file make sure you have added `jquery.min.js` or you have that `min js` make sure it's top of all other js

Comment: Yes, I added, but now it does nothing. I press REGISTER button it does nothing and there is no error

Comment: Okkk now go to the network tab of console and check what's going is your server side url in your case `form.attr('action')` has been hit or not what it returns apply some debugging skills.

Comment: @Curiousdev IT gives this https://yadi.sk/i/3tajtwBJ3KsQGT

Comment: Ohhh that's great it gives you `200 OK` response now in your `success` function `console.log(response)` or you can put a debug in `success` function and check the response that's it

Comment: @Curiousdev i did this 

success:function(response) {    
    if(response.success == true) {
     console.log(response); 
     
    }


it throws nothing))

Comment: put it before `if` condition

Comment: it again gives nothing) also i wrote alert it did nothing

Comment: Ohh now dis is the all possibilities i can see from here dude if you have hosted this anywhere give me that link so i can analyze what's goin wrong :(

Comment: @Curiousdev you mean the website or code?

Comment: website would be better

Comment: do you have teamviewer?))

Comment: yes i have that

Comment: Your a are not sending any response through to ajax. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkHS9QLmlxI

Comment: Ajax is a separate technology and has nothing to do with CI. Please move this to a discussion.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 oh thanks, it worked very well! But how can I echo validation errors under the field, not on the top?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the `dynamic binding` issue.

Maybe you are calling the ready function before the JQuery Javascript is included?

Here is your error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at register.js:

```
// Remove This.
//$(document).ready(function() {  
//$("#registrationform").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
//   var form = $(this);

// Add This.
$('#your_model_id').on('click', '.submit_button_class', function(e) {

var str = $( "#registrationform" ).serialize();
```

And Please You should put the references to the jquery scripts first.
like this.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="your_script.js"></script>
```

Comment: it did nothing. first i put:

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>

then 

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/js/ajax/register.js"></script>

Comment: Regarding Your Error I have suggested the script. Have you tried that?